# sas cumulative return multiple variables

Tags: loops, sas

I've been running a datastep for computing the cumulutive product of a variable X1, giving it a starting value of 1. However, I'm unable to run it for several variables using a %do loop. I provide both codes below. Help appreciated.

```
DATA HAVE;
INFILE DATALINES DSD;
INPUT X1 X2 X3 YEAR;
DATALINES;
0.99,0.98, 0.97,2005
0.975,0.96, 0.923,2006
0.983,0.934, 0.93,2007
0.978,0.93, 0.887,2008
;

data working;
set have;
retain R1 1;
S1=R1*X1;
output;
R1=S1;
drop S1;
run;


%macro macro5(j);
data notworking;
set have;
%DO i=1 %to &j;
retain R&i 1;
S&i=R&i*X&i;
output;
R&i=S&i;
drop S&i;
%end;
run;
%mend;
%macro5(3);
```

Comment: I think this is more designed for an array not a macro do loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array, not a macro loop here.

```
DATA HAVE;
INFILE DATALINES DSD;
INPUT X1 X2 X3 YEAR;
DATALINES;
0.99,0.98, 0.97,2005
0.975,0.96, 0.923,2006
0.983,0.934, 0.93,2007
0.978,0.93, 0.887,2008
;

data want;
set have;
array x(3) x1-x3;
array r(3) r1-r3;

retain r1-r3 1;

output;

do i=1 to 3;
r(i)=x(i)*r(i);
end;

drop i;
run;
```